How can I do commands such as "print()" without there popping up an error message?
I am trying to teach myself the very basics of R but I can't even get past the very simple print command. Everytime I try to even just put a variable like x <- 2 and then do print(x) it just says "error: object 'x' not found". Why is this? Can I fix this? None of the other commands work either.
I tried just doing simple commands to see if any of them actually work but none of them do, no matter what variable I put and how I put it, the same error keeps showing up. I tried to look into whether I am misspelling my variables or if I was giving them invalid names but I am at like hour 3 of trying to teach myself this so I am very unsure about what to do.
